# ASP.NET get cell from DataRow in a datatable?

Tags: asp.net

I was wondering how I could access the cells in a dataTable? I thought I could do something like

```
  foreach (DataRow siteRow in sites.Rows)
        {
            String siteName = siteRow.Cells[1].Text;
        }
```

but that doesn't seem to work like it would with a gridview. What should I do?

Answer (score 6):

Use the [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.item.aspx):

```
foreach (DataRow siteRow in sites.Rows)
{
    String siteName = siteRow[1].ToString(); // second column
    // or via name:
    siteName = siteRow["SiteName"].ToString; // if column name is SiteName
    // or even better via Field method which is strongly typed 
    // and supports nullable types:
    siteName = siteRow.Field<string>(1); // works also via name
}
```

Comment: Ah of course! Makes me wonder why gridviewrow even has a cells method